# Xamarin IOS Test Flight App crashes during the initial launch

Tags: xamarin.ios, testflight

Attached the crash log for your reference.
We have a Xamarin IOS application. We can able to launch the application in Debug mode and after we submit the app to Testflight and try open the APP, its crashing during the initial launch itself. Any pointers on this would help us a lot to proceed further
Incident Identifier: 95079E01-A8C9-43B8-9BE7-A6B2F810A6EA
Hardware Model:      iPhone12,1
Process:             idms.app.iOS [498]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/86207EA9-EFC6-4B91-88DA-EB48B554FA38/idms.app.iOS.app/idms.app.iOS
Identifier:          com.enerpac.IntegrityAssured-b
Version:             1.1.0 (5.0.1)
AppStoreTools:       15C5500a
AppVariant:          1:iPhone12,1:17
Beta:                YES
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.enerpac.IntegrityAssured-b [655]

Date/Time:           2024-01-23 17:58:10.0780 +0530
Launch Time:         2024-01-23 17:58:09.7078 +0530
OS Version:          iPhone OS 17.2.1 (21C66)
Release Type:        User
Baseband Version:    5.00.00
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  0

Kernel Triage:
VM - (arg = 0x3) mach_vm_allocate_kernel failed within call to vm_map_enter
Thread 0 name:
Thread 0 name:
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001fcd3dfbc __pthread_kill + 8 (:-1)
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000021f5eb680 pthread_kill + 268 (pthread.c:1681)
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001bd6adb90 abort + 180 (abort.c:118)
3   idms.app.iOS                    0x0000000107789a38 0x104748000 + 50600504
4   idms.app.iOS                    0x0000000107651288 0x104748000 + 49320584

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000021f5e79fc start_wqthread + 0 (:-1)

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000021f5e79fc start_wqthread + 0 (:-1)

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000021f5e79fc start_wqthread + 0 (:-1)
Thread 4 name:
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001fcd35b1c __psynch_cvwait + 8 (:-1)
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000021f5e6fd4 _pthread_cond_wait + 1228 (pthread_cond.c:862)
2   idms.app.iOS                    0x0000000107754fb8 0x104748000 + 50384824
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000021f5e84d4 _pthread_start + 136 (pthread.c:904)
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000021f5e7a10 thread_start + 8 (:-1)

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x0000000000000000
x4: 0x0000000000000022   x5: 0x000000010ae98800   x6: 0x0000000000001000   x7: 0xffffffff00000600
x8: 0x2a44964933437989   x9: 0x2a44964b35c43289  x10: 0x00000000000002ee  x11: 0x0000000000000000
x12: 0x000000010ad86600  x13: 0x00000001082d79cb  x14: 0x00000000000000e0  x15: 0x0000000080000000
x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x0000000206874b00  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
x20: 0x0000000000000103  x21: 0x0000000206874be0  x22: 0x0000000000000000  x23: 0x000000010a820600
x24: 0x00000001082d79c8  x25: 0x000000016b6b4fa0  x26: 0x0000000000000002  x27: 0x0000000107b32960
x28: 0x0000000000ffffff   fp: 0x000000016b6b41a0   lr: 0x000000021f5eb680
sp: 0x000000016b6b4180   pc: 0x00000001fcd3dfbc cpsr: 0x40000000
esr: 0x56000080  Address size fault

Binary Images:
0x104748000 -         0x1078e7fff idms.app.iOS arm64   /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/86207EA9-EFC6-4B91-88DA-EB48B554FA38/idms.app.iOS.app/idms.app.iOS
0x107da8000 -         0x107de7fff DXGrid arm64  <95813323f6c63a1792fde7a92b3fa813> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/86207EA9-EFC6-4B91-88DA-EB48B554FA38/idms.app.iOS.app/Frameworks/DXGrid.framework/DXGrid
0x107e78000 -         0x107ef7fff DXEditors arm64  <914fbc2e896b36c3be3fbe7a430436ed> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/86207EA9-EFC6-4B91-88DA-EB48B554FA38/idms.app.iOS.app/Frameworks/DXEditors.framework/DXEditors
0x10800c000 -         0x10802ffff DXListView arm64  <9b111686a33f319f8443fd5c76cd2e5d> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/86207EA9-EFC6-4B91-88DA-EB48B554FA38/idms.app.iOS.app/Frameworks/DXListView.framework/DXListView
0x10d864000 -         0x10d86ffff libobjc-trampolines.dylib arm64e  <26d68e81199a300dbc1530ba4630a611> /private/preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/lib/libobjc-trampolines.dylib
0x1b459c000 -         0x1b50fbfff Foundation arm64e   /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x1b5602000 -         0x1b5b2efff CoreFoundation arm64e   /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x1b782d000 -         0x1b9302fff UIKitCore arm64e  <99ad2a319360369f9c0ba7a0af33e2e7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore
0x1bd638000 -         0x1bd6b5ff3 libsystem_c.dylib arm64e  <6e5a7692c1e935adb20bc307991df11c> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x1d8355000 -         0x1d83dcb5b dyld arm64e  <630c2209dfd73c72b0a9e856c560f123> /usr/lib/dyld
0x1f8b8b000 -         0x1f8b93fff GraphicsServices arm64e  <7d6f670c0e4b32158b4e599ef1ab9ed2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x1fcd34000 -         0x1fcd6cfef libsystem_kernel.dylib arm64e  <55f2cc41248837bdbb95ea2ffd7611ae> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x21f5e6000 -         0x21f5f1ff3 libsystem_pthread.dylib arm64e   /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib

EOF
Last few lines of the crash log is attached

Comment: Is there any more crash log information? If so, please add it.

Comment: Thanks for the response. will add the entire log

Comment: Please refer the below link for full crash log https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/15856

Comment: Did you try to use release mood?

Comment: Configuration to deploy to Testflight is exactly similar to Release configuration. we named it as UAT configuration. using this mode, if we deploy to Testflight App crashes. Hope you got a chance to look into the crashlog which I have provided from Testflight. If yes, do you see any potential issue with that ?

Comment: In the log information, I find you deployed the project on iOS17.2.1. Is this issue also occurring on other iOS versions? Besides, Xcode 15.1/15.2 is supported by [Visual Studio 2022 version 17.8.5 and Visual Studio 2022 version 17.9 Preview 3](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/releases), so you should ensure your Xcode and VS versions are right. And Xamarin.iOS no longer supported new APIs after Xcode15, Did you use new APIs in your project?

Comment: Thanks Sean for the update, I am using VS version 17.6.8 and xcode 15.1. I will try upgrading my VS and check once. As far as APIs are concerned, we are using Web API calls where in our DB resides in Azure. Please share more specific information on the new APIs which needs to be used ?

Comment: Hello Sean, Now, I have upgraded my VS to 17.8.5 and used xamarin ios SDK 16.2 to build a project, archived and published successfully to App store. This version is not crashing but App is not opening , blank black screen comes up and stays .

Comment: Also, tried building it using the xamarin ios SDK 17.2 to build a project, archived and published successfully to App store. App is not crashing but on my iphone on 17.2 still the same behavior, blank black screen comes up. what could be the issue here, need your inputs please

Comment: The blank black screen problem also occurred on an empty Xamrin.iOS project? Or did you try to use iOS emulator on VS to run the project?

Comment: We have a login screen which opens up when the application is launched, when I try a debug, it works fine, only with Testflight version its showing us blank screen. Same with Emulator too..

Comment: Do you mean when you deploy the app to the physical iOS device by VS and the emulator by VS, they work normally?

Comment: I mean to say, Debug version of the APP works fine, only with the Testflight version we are facing crash issues, we are seeing this behavior even with simulator too.. As of now clueless whats going wrong

Comment: Update : We have succefully cracked the issue, this issue was because of the Babel package which we have used in our APP. When we were pushing the release to Testflight Babel package was enabled and during debug mode , it was switched off. Had to do some Babel configuration changes to fix this issue .

Comment: Congratulation. You can post your solution as this issue's answer. It would be helpful for others who also meet similar problem.

Comment: <!--<DynamicProxy>All</DynamicProxy>--> this setting was causing an issue, so commented this and it started working